# Mysql transaction commits are not in order?

Tags: mysql, transactions

There are 3 concurrent mysql sessions.2 writing to table1 and one reading from table1. All the 3 sessions refers to a unique lock before executing the transaction, this is used to grantee that no one will read/write at the same time to table1

### Session 1

```
START TRANSACTION
SELECT id FROM global_lock WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE;
t1 = GetCurrentTimeMills() // used psuedo code here
INSERT INTO table1 (value, updated) VALUES ('v1', t1);
COMMIT;
```

### Session 2

```
START TRANSACTION
SELECT id FROM global_lock WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE;
t2 = GetCurrentTimeMills()  // used pseudo code here
INSERT INTO table1 (value, updated) VALUES ('v2', t2);
COMMIT;
```

### Session 3

```
START TRANSACTION
SELECT id FROM global_lock WHERE id=1 FOR UPDATE;
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE updated> t1 -1;
COMMIT;
```

- Session 3 returns the value created at t2 only. It's missing the value created at t1 which is earlier than t2.
- If I execute the session 3 for the second time, I get both values created at t1 and t2.

I'm using InnoDB engine with mysql 5.7.17. I assume that mysql in someway doesn't honor the commit order.

How to avoid this kind of situation, is there any workaround for this or a configuration change to enforce mysql to honor commit order?

Comment: Are the 3 sessions run concurrently without order? And what is the isolation level used (via `select @@tx_isolation;`)

Comment: @Jacky Yes as mentioned at the very beginning these are concurrent sessions. Isolation level is the default which is REPEATABLE-READ

Comment: If the sessions are run without order, what is the meaning of honoring the commit order?

Comment: If the read (session 3) happens first, obviously, we could not get the t1

Comment: @Jacky Actually all three transactions require a global unique lock. So I believe even they starts the transaction at the same time, they cannot reach the commit simultaneously, meaning the first one  who got the lock will be able to commit first.

Comment: @Jacky If the session 3 happens first it shouldn't get either of t1 or t2.